# CloudWatch filter pattern for ruby logger

Tags: ruby, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

With AWS CloudWatch Logs, i'd like apply a filter, separating the fields in a message generated by a ruby logger.

```
I, [26/Oct/2015:04:35:12 +0000#11]  INFO -- : (0.000934s) BEGIN
```

This is how the format is specified according to the Ruby docs:

```
SeverityID, [DateTime #pid] SeverityLabel -- ProgName: message
```

How do i extract the labels using a CloudWatch filter? Namely, how can i extract values between certain characters like the pID and parts of the actual message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the short answer is that you cannot do that.

If logging in json format is an option you could potentially do something around extracting fields/values.

Docs are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

Comment: I see. Changing the logging format is absolutely an option. Thank you!